# How to replace a numerical Scatter Plot axis with Text values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Please see below for my current graph and table:

[image: Data Table]

[image]

1. I would like to replace the the X-Axis (0, 1, 2, 3...) with the corresponding letter grades in the table (B, B+, A-...) and still maintain the order of the table.
2. I'd like to add the name of the animal to each dot, so for example the dot at (5, 11000000) would have "Dog" next to it.

Can anyone provide detailed instructions on how to accomplish this? I can't find the first item anywhere.

Updates based on Rory's suggestion to use line charts:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Better suited for SuperUser.com

Comment: @ScottCraner thank you for the tip, I just opened an account over there and posted

Comment: Why use an XY scatter at all? Use a line chart with markers but no lines, and a category axis.

Comment: ^^^^^^^^ THIS ^^^^^^^^^^.

Comment: @Rory thank you for the suggestions. Would it be possible to post a few more details on how to add a category axis?

Comment: Just use the average rating column for the axis values. It will default to category.

Comment: @Rory see what happens when I add another animal with the same grade. This method doesnt overlap on the xAxis and it wont order them properly. See original answer edit

Comment: @Rory hopefully this isnt too much to ask but would it be possible for you to do a quick screen recording of what you are suggesting?

Comment: If you have multiple entries for the same grade then you will need an XY scatter and add a dummy series with data labels to use as axis labels. Jon Peltier and Andy Pope's websites have examples of this.

Comment: @Rory thank you for the tip. I'm not familiar with their websites. Is there a link you may be able to provide to one of these? This peltiertech website seems somewhat broken

Comment: Jon's site does appear to be broken, and I can't find the one I was thinking of on Andy's site at the moment. Basically you just plot a dummy series of 0 Y values and the existing X values, apply data labels, then add custom text. If that's not enough info, ask on SuperUser. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FinDev, I posted the answer on your question in Super User.

Answer found here: https://superuser.com/questions/1598217/how-to-replace-a-numerical-scatter-plot-axis-with-text-values

Comment: thank you for the help! I just posted a comment on your superuser post with a follow up question